# Errors while doing Binary Search in Python . What is wrong with the code?

Tags: python

```
import math 

def BinarySearch( A , val , low , high ):
    if high < low :
        return -1 #not found 
    mid = low + (high - low ) /2 
    if A[mid] > val:
        return BinarySearch(A,val , low , high )
    if A[mid] < val :
        return BinarySearch(A,val,low,high)
    else: 
        return mid #found 


A = [ 12 , 23 , 2 , 33 , 123 , 4 , 5 , 2 , 54 , 555 , 21 ]
BinarySearch( A , 0 , 0, 10)
```

I tried to do Binary Search without using the bisect Module . But it gives an error such as this

```
 File "doubtrob.py", line 8, in BinarySearch
    return BinarySearch(A,val , low , high )
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using exactly the same search space on each iteration. Also, you need to stop when high - low < 2, otherwise mid will eventually equal low, and you might still be stuck in an infinite loop.

As an aside, you can get `mid` more simply: `(low + high)/2`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def BinarySearch( A , val , low , high ):
    if high < low :
        return -1 #not found                                                                                                                                 
    mid = low + (high - low ) /2
    if A[mid] > val:
        return BinarySearch(A, val , low , mid-1 )
    if A[mid] < val :
        return BinarySearch(A, val, mid+1 ,high)
    else:
        return mid #found
```

recursion must have a end point. You are calling same parameters ever time so, it will never satisfy the `high<low`, so never `terminates`.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In the 2 return BinarySearch() calls, you keep calling it with the same parameters, so it keeps looping to the same spot on the next call, which keeps calling with the same parameters...

This is really a homework question. Hint Ends.